# .NET Runtime Object Browser

Tags: c#, .net, browser, inspection

Is there a framework which can be used in your application, to make it expose internal objects on some port for inspection.

for.e.g. after i start my application in this case a GUI Application, and then say launch http://localhost:9100 then it should show me the statistics of the app.

I played a bit with HttpListener accepting connections and then outputting raw HTML, it works fine for simple tasks, but there is too much worked involved if i have make a proper object browser.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you clarify your use-case a little more?  Are you trying to list entities which the application manages?  Are you trying to monitor the object-graph of all objects in the process?

Comment: Yes i want to develop a generic object inspector, the one which lists all the entites which i want to expose in the application. I can do it easily in-process by going through the objects using reflection, what i want is the same functionality but over http. so if my App is running on a PC, then i want the Object Browser to be viewed over http on some other pc using any browser.

Answer (score 0):

No, there aren't really any libraries that I'm familiar with. You would want something like visual studio implemented with it's runtime debug objet browser. That however is not an exposed API so you'd have to make your own.

As far as exposing the endpoint, you can use WCF to easily expose a TCP service (or whatever else, but NetTcp is just so easy) as an entrypoint into the functionality you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Fiddler as a framework and write your own plugins in .net!
Check it out
http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler2/extensions.asp

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want, its not a framework, but a tool, but you can use [.Net Memory Validator](http://www.softwareverify.com/dotNet/memory/index.html) to see which objects (and how many of them) are allocated in your application. You need to look at the [Objects](http://www.softwareverify.com/dotNet/memory/objects.html) tab.

You need to launch your app with DNMV - you can't view an already running process.